# Unable to access facebook login?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am using Facebook's official Android SDK, and I am administrator of an app on Facebook.

I read that by default, the app is in sandbox mode and no one except administrator and developers can access it. I am using it to add Facebook login facility in my android app. However, I added my friends, who are developing the app with me as developers, but they cant log in via Facebook with their account credentials from the app. I disabled the sandbox mode for app from Facebook's app settings, still they cant access the login facility. Once they click on Facebook login button, they are redirected to the same activity without anything happening, whereas in my case, I login successfully and the app proceeds normally.

Are there any extra settings I need to do in order to make it public?

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you enabled the deep linking and facebook login in facebook app?

Comment: And the app installed from the same system or different?

Comment: actually, I am not able to put it in correct words..I have registered a new app on developers.facebook.com and I am using the app-id of that newly created app into my android app's code. I want to use Facebook login facility in my android app...

Comment: You were saying that you are able to login but your friends are not able.

Comment: Yup, I am able to login to facebook from my android app using the Facebook SDK's code and obtain a GraphUser object containing my information. However, when my friends log in with their credentials then it simply returns at the login screen repetitively..

Comment: This problem normally obtains when the facebook app in the phone is not updated. Please cross check it.

Comment: They tested on their cells so I am not sure about that...still, I think the login process is done by Facebook SDK and does not involve Facebook app in the phone...because one of them doesnt have it installed, still it gets the login screen. But that screen repeats after trying to log in..

Comment: Ya onwards Facebook SDK 3.0 the login is completed by the facebook app. If the app is not installed on the phone then it will promt you to a login dialog.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34093/discussion-between-tigerden-and-abhishek-agarwal)

Answer (score 2):

```
       Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            // callback when session changes state
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {
                if (session.isOpened()) {
                    // make request to the /me API

                    List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
                    if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                        pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                                RegisterActivity.this, PERMISSIONS);
                        session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                        return;
                    }
                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                        // callback after Graph API response with
                        // user object
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                Response response) {
                            if (user == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        RegisterActivity.this
                                        .getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Facebook Error",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        RegisterActivity.this
                                        .getApplicationContext(),
                                        user.getName()
                                        + " Logged in Successfully.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                GraphUser abc = user;

                                id = user.getId();
                                name = user.getName();
                                gender = user.getProperty("gender")
                                        .toString();
                                editname.setText(name);
                                username.setText(user.getUsername());
                                JSONObject jo = user
                                        .getInnerJSONObject();
                                Log.d("Details", jo.toString());
                                try {
                                    emailid.setText(user
                                            .getProperty("email")
                                            .toString());
                                } catch (Exception e1) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch
                                    // block
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                try {
                                    location = user.getLocation()
                                            .getProperty("name")
                                            .toString();
                                } catch (Exception e) {

                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }



                            }

                            return;
                        }

                    });

                }
            }
        });
```

Put **onActivityResult** Method

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
            resultCode, data);
}
```

**isSubsetoff()** Method

```
   private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset,
        Collection<String> superset) {
    for (String string : subset) {
        if (!superset.contains(string)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

and the **permissions** as per your need

```
  private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("email",
        "user_about_me", "user_location", "user_checkins");
```