# Fetch Facebook user details in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am developed a app in android in which i fetch user details from Facebook. I am able to fetch user name, firstname, lastname but email comes null in some Facebook account. In some Facebook account I found email id and some Facebook account email is null why?

Comment: because of they not entered or they restrict their mail from others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the email permission this is the working code for getting email id.
It is given by me here
[Unable to access facebook login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840019/unable-to-access-facebook-login)

```
  Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            // callback when session changes state
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {
                if (session.isOpened()) {
                    // make request to the /me API

                    List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
                    if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                        pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                                RegisterActivity.this, PERMISSIONS);
                        session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                        return;
                    }
                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                        // callback after Graph API response with
                        // user object
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                Response response) {
                            if (user == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        RegisterActivity.this
                                        .getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Facebook Error",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        RegisterActivity.this
                                        .getApplicationContext(),
                                        user.getName()
                                        + " Logged in Successfully.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                GraphUser abc = user;

                                id = user.getId();
                                name = user.getName();
                                gender = user.getProperty("gender")
                                        .toString();
                                editname.setText(name);
                                username.setText(user.getUsername());
                                JSONObject jo = user
                                        .getInnerJSONObject();
                                Log.d("Details", jo.toString());
                                try {
                                    emailid.setText(user
                                            .getProperty("email")
                                            .toString());
                                } catch (Exception e1) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch
                                    // block
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                try {
                                    location = user.getLocation()
                                            .getProperty("name")
                                            .toString();
                                } catch (Exception e) {

                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }



                            }

                            return;
                        }

                    });

                }
            }
        });
```

Put **onActivityResult** Method

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
            resultCode, data);
}
```

**isSubsetoff()** Method

```
   private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset,
        Collection<String> superset) {
    for (String string : subset) {
        if (!superset.contains(string)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

and the **permissions** as per your need

```
  private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("email",
        "user_about_me", "user_location");
```

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.parkhya.treebidsale/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: com.facebook.FacebookException: Cannot call LoginActivity with a null calling package. This can occur if the launchMode of the caller is singleInstance.