# cocos2d-x using facebook android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, cocos2d-x, facebook-android-sdk

I am integrating Facebook android SDK 3.6 on my cocos2d-x-2.1.4 app.

[According to the docs here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook).

I need to create a FragmentActivity to initializes the Facebook SDK.But I don't know how to write it in cocos2d-x, because the activity in cocos2d-x is so different.

Could anyone help me? How can I initializes facebook SDK and login easily?

Comment: Are you writing your game using C++

Comment: No, I am using android

Comment: I am asking for language not for platform.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I am using Java, not C++

Comment: there should be a cocos-2dxActivity extending in your launcher activity you have to define all your Facebook integration code in this activity.

Comment: yes, I am trying, but it seems this Activity do not support Fragment, so I cannot do it like docs says.

Comment: Don't use fragments trying to use this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848764/fetch-facebook-user-details-in-android/17849900#17849900

Comment: Now I can see the prompt for additional permissions:App would like to access your public profile and friend list, likes and status updates. but in the method onSessionStateChange(), it always show "Logged out...", state.isClosed() is always true...

Comment: where are you using this method? Is it working?

Comment: I added a Login button, and wrote a onClickLogin method, in this method I did used your method [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848764/fetch-facebook-user-details-in-android/17849900#17849900). and I added onSessionStateChange() just like docs says. Now when I press the Login button, I can see the prompt for additional permissions, but Log shows "Logged out..."

Comment: If your are using my method then there is no need of onSessionStateChanged() method just follow the links steps.

Comment: then how can I send a request? I am now using WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(), but I cannot send a request, because session.isOpened() is false, I Logged in first, but the session is still closed

Comment: Try simplest approach by using plugin (in case if you want to save time). Try EziSocial SDK. They have free version for login and sharing status on Facebook, twitter. http://www.ezibyte.com

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233042/how-to-login-facebook-using-sdk-4-1-0-in-android/30233276#30233276